# Cast Flow/TypeScript JavaScript object value types to non-nullable

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I have the following type

```js
type MyObject = $ReadOnly<{
  foo: ?number,
  bar: ?number,
  baz: ?number,
}>;
```

and I want to convert all the values to non-nullable, e.g;

```js
type MyNonNullValuesObject = $ReadOnly<{
  foo: number,
  bar: number,
  baz: number,
}>;
```

What's a good way to do so in Flow without repeating all the keys? I'm looking to use the `$NonMaybeType<T>` utility to help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow provides an `$ObjMap` utility type which you can use to map over the values and turn them into non-nullables via `$NonMaybeType`.

```js
type MyObject = $ReadOnly<{
  foo: ?number,
  bar: ?number,
  baz: ?number,
}>;

type NonMaybeValueType = <V>(V) => $NonMaybeType<V>;
type MyNonNullValuesObject = $ObjMap<MyObject, NonMaybeValueType>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In typescript this would be:

```
type MyObject = Readonly<{
  foo: number | null,
  bar: number | null,
  baz: number | null,
}>;

type NonNullableObject<T> = { [K in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[K]> };

type MyNonNullableObject = NonNullableObject<MyObject>;
```

[Mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) using [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet) utility.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsKBeKAlCAhgCYD2AdgDYgA8A3gFBRQBmJJAXFGQK4C2iEAE5QAPl24UKAGkZREBQZx78ho8ZJlN5ALyV8BwsTw30AvgD4A3PXqhIUAHLkHEigUQUISVBmoAVc2woWigAbQBpKABLMigAawgQEmYoPwBdTicyF0l3T38ItMDTa1twaDgsnLcPLxR0TBwq1zy6n2BqOG8Gq3ogA)